# Blood Bowl Not Working

Tags: windows, wine

Blood Bowl (a windows game) is not working on computer (which runs Ubuntu) even though I am running blood bowl using wine. It runs however it does not create a window. You can here the music playing but see nothing. The version is chaos edition and the rating is silver. I'm running wine 1.4.1 and the Ubuntu is 13.04. I cannot find a fullscreen option in the config. Help? I'm a newbie ...

Comment: What is wrong with it? Does it not start? If so, what error are you getting?

Comment: is it supported? how did you install it? (complete procedure) what is not working? what exactly is happening? Did it successfully install? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Alvar Blood Bowl [is supported](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10008)

Comment: you might want to refer to [the AppDB page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10008) for this game. There are a number of different versions with multiple ratings, but they include various fixes for running the game.

Comment: @FantasyFreak Which version do you have installed? Which version of wine do you have installed? Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: To find the version of wine type `wine --version` in a Terminal session. Type `cat /etc/issue` to find the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to fix your problem:

1. Run `cd ~/.wine/drive_c && gksudo nautilus "Program Files (x86)/Steam/SteamApps/common"`
2. Type your password
3. Open the Blood Bowl folder
4. Search the folder for config.xml and open it
5. Set Shader to 0 and Fullscreen to 1

You can see the full fix [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27598).

Comment: Sorry. Wrong path. I updated the code.

Comment: Fixed command. Now includes cd to access ~